# How to fix "Compile Error: User defined type not defined" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently setting a trading algorithm using a University's trading API. Keep in mind I am fairly new to VBA, but I am just confused as to why my code is throwing a compile error in the following snippet:

I've tried declaring my parameters type but this doesn't help either. I haven't made any custom types as you can see in the snippet.

```
Private Declare Sub AppSleep Lib “kerne132” Alias “Sleep” (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Public Sub Pause(PauseInSeconds As Long)
    Call AppSleep(PauseInSeconds * 1000)
End Sub


Function marketmake(time, triggerstart, triggerstop)
    ‘To initialize the API
DIm api As RIT2.API
Set API = New RIT2.API 
‘Run the algo during certain time frame in the simulation
If time < triggerstart And time > triggerstop Then
    ‘Check if any orders are backlogged, if not, then put in a bracket
    If Sheets(“Open Orders”).Cells(1, 2) = “” Then
        ‘The following loop submits the Buy section of bracket 
    Status = False
        Do While Status = False 
        Status = API.AddOrder(“ALGO”, Range(“Shares”), Range(“MidMarket”) - Range(“Spread”), API.SELL, API.LMT)
        Loop

‘The following loop submits the Sell section of bracket 
    Status = False
        Do While Status = False 
        Status = API.AddOrder(“ALGO”, Range(“Shares”), Range(“MidMarket”) - Range(“Spread”), API.BUY, API.LMT)
        Loop

ElseIf InStr(Sheets(“Open Orders”).Cells(2,1), “;” = 0 Then
    ‘Cancel all orders
    API.CancelOrderExpr (“price > 0”)
    End If 
    Marketmake = time + triggerstart
End If 
End Function
```

basically my algorithm is suppose to buy shares up to a set bid price, then break out of the loop when either the necessary shares were bought or loop duration has reached some arbitrary runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing bracket on your Instr

```
ElseIf InStr(Sheets("Open Orders").Cells(2, 1), ";") = 0 Then
```

Replace smart quotes with proper quotes.

If using 64 bit you need to add PtrSafe as well

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub AppSleep Lib "kerne132" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

And this

```
Dim API As RIT2.API
Set API = New RIT2.API
```

relies on you have a class called `RIT2`